# How to determine if copy() is successful?

Tags: php

I can copy remote image to my server with;

```
@copy("http://www.example.com/image.jpg", $title.'.jpg');
```

But I want to make sure it has been copied successfully. I want to do something if it has not been copied succesfully. How can I do that ? Thanks.

Comment: Well, a *really* good start would be reading the documentation.  http://us2.php.net/copy. In particular, read what the return value is.  -1.

Comment: `copy` returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

Comment: also avoid using `@` because it hides errors

Comment: This question seems perfectly clear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(!copy("http://www.example.com/image.jpg", $title.'.jpg')){
    echo "failed to copy file...\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. ** - according to the documentation which you didn't read I suppose.